# How can I sum two fileds from different tables in PIG?

Tags: sum, field, apache-pig

table example:

```
A = LOAD 'data' AS (a1:int,a2:int);

DUMP A;
(1,2)
(1,3)
(2,2)
(3,4)
(3,1)
```

and I get

```
A2 = GROUP A BY a1;

DUMP A2;
(1,{(1,2),(1,3)})
(2,{(2,2)})
(3,{(3,4),(3,1)})

B = LOAD 'data2' AS (b1:int,b2:int);
(1,4)
(2,3)
(3,2)
```

The results that I want are

```
(1,{(1,6),(1,7)})
(2,{(2,5)})
(3,{(3,6),(3,3)})
```

That is,

```
FOREACH A2 GENERATE group,A.a2+B.b2
```

WHERE A.a1==B.b1 but the error shows :

```
Invalid scalar projection: B
```

Any thoughts would be great,thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to do join first and then add and then do group by.

```
joined_data = JOIN A by a1, B by b1;
summed_data = FOREACH joined_data GENERATE a1 as a1,a2+b2 as sum;
final_answer = GROUP summed_data by a1;
```